# Spring: JUnit tests with session scope: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionTestBean'

Tags: java, spring, session, junit4, spring-test

I tried to follow the guidelines at https://tarunsapra.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/junit-spring-session-and-request-scope-beans/
 or https://touk.pl/blog/2011/04/15/how-to-test-spring-session-scoped-beans/ .
However, I cannot get my session beans autowired in a JUnit4 test.

Maybe it is just some stupid error, however I cannot find it.

I use spring-test 4.3.22.RELEASE (together with various other spring-libraries) and junit-4.12.jar

Here is my trivial example (tested in eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a))

TrivialSessionTest.java

```
package demo;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/trivialApplicationContextForSessions.xml" })
@ComponentScan("demo")
public class TrivialSessionTests  {

@Autowired
protected SessionTestBean sessionTestBean;

@Test
public void testLogin() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Hello World", sessionTestBean.getSomething());
}

}
```

SessionTestBean.java

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SessionTestBean {

public SessionTestBean() {}

public String getSomething() {
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

spring/trivialApplicationContextForSessions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

<bean id="sessionScopeConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="session">
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="request">
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestScope" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Running the test results in

```
[main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener     [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@73e132e0] to prepare test instance [demo.TrivialSessionTests@3773862a]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo.TrivialSessionTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionTestBean'; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'demo.SessionTestBean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after intensive further trial, I finally found the problem(s):

1. I needed an additional @org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
   for the test. This configuration also takes care for the session-scoping.
2. @ComponentScan("demo") does not seem to work on a test class. I had to put it into the ...applicationContext.xml
3. Finally: The session-scope declaration in  does not seem to be necessary (and proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS neither)

So the running example is as follows

TrivialSessionTests.java

```
package demo;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@org.junit.runner.RunWith(org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/trivialApplicationContextForSessions.xml" })
@org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
public class TrivialSessionTests {

    @Autowired()
    protected SessionTestBean sessionTestBean;

    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Hello World", sessionTestBean.getSomething());
    }
}
```

SessionTestBean.java

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component(value="sessionTestBean")
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SessionTestBean {

    public SessionTestBean() {}

    public String getSomething() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

trivialApplicationContextForSessions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="demo" />
</beans>
```